# Model class is not loading in cakephp 3.0 helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to load a Model class in a user define helper function in cakephp 3.0 ? Import is not working

Comment: Using Models in Helpers will break MVC and is a no-go. This will just end up in hard to maintain spaghetti code. If I see things like that in the code reviews I do, I immediately know this app has architectural problems. Re-think your approach to whatever you do, this is wrong,.

Comment: This is just for debugging process at local server. On production definitely, architectural process will be followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

`TableRegistry::get('Model');`

ow and don't forget to include the namespace:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
```

Comment: Downvoted because technically this will work **but** at the same time it violates MVC and causes code smell.

Comment: agreed, but you should take that up with the one asking the question